# Matrix Polynomial Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a matrix with complex coefficients. Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial of minimal positive degree with property that $f(A)=0$. Let $P_A(x)$ be characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Prove that $p_A(x)=g(x) f(x)$, for some polynomial $g(x)$. ($x$ is scalar)

Comment: Write $P_A = q f + r$ for some polynomials $q,r$, with $r$ of degree less than $f$. If $r \neq 0$, what can you say about $r(A)$ and why is this a contradiction?

Comment: @copper.hat I can prove that $p_A(A) = g(A)f(A)$. But why $P_A(x)= g(x)f(x)$, for any $x$?

Comment: If $P_A = q f + r$, then it is easy to see that $r(A) = 0$. However, if $r \neq 0$, then the degree of $r$ is less than $f$ which is a contradiction ($f$ is the minimal polynomial). Hence $r=0$ and so you can write $P_A = q f$ (as polynomials in $x$).

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwan I do not see how is your point related to this discussion.

Comment: I meant I can prove it using Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Marc: let's keep comments constructive and civil.

Comment: @vadim123: Understood, I'll remove my comments. I never meant anything personal though, it is just my surprise at the fact that the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which I personally find a hard nut to crack, is often taken as self-evident.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : surprisingly and unusually enough, one the easiest and simplest proofs of the C-H theorem I know appears in the "Outline of Theory and Problems of Linear Algebra", by Lipschutz - Lipson, in the...yes, in the Schaum's Series! Try it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I unfortunately have no access to that book, maybe you'd care to give me a hint of what is used? I know quite a few proofs, so just a small hint will probably suffice, something like "reduce to the diagonalisable case" for instance. But on the other hand we're digressing...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Never mind, Google provided me a clandestine copy of the book. As far as I can see the proof is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Hamilton_theorem#A_direct_algebraic_proof) from the WP article (the editing of which I had some involvement with).

Comment: Well @MarcvanLeeuwen, most probably the Wiki proof is the one from the book, which preceedes the web as we know it loooooong years....:)

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent statement of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, over fields which is what we are concerned with here, is that the characteristic polynomial of any square matrix is divisible by its minimal polynomial, see for instance the lead of its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Hamilton_theorem). I don't assume you are asking for a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, so I'll just comment on the equivalence.

If $K$ is the base field (I suppose it is the real or complex numbers in this question), then the ring $K[X]$ of polynomials is a principal ideal domain, and in fact a Euclidean domain (more properly stated, it is a principal ideal domain exactly because Euclidean division by any nonzero polynomial in $K[X]$ is defined). This means (in particular) that the set of polynomial that vanish under some substitution operation (which form an ideal) can always be described as the set of (polynomial) multiples of one particular polynomial, called a generator of the ideal. This can be shown using Euclidean division: if you take a nonzero polynomial $P$ of minimal degree that vanishes under the substitution, then any other polynomial $Q$ vanishes if and only if its remainder after Euclidean division by $P$ vanishes, but given the minimality of $P$ this can only happen if the remainder is zero.

This is at the basis of the definition of the minimal polynomial of a matrix (or linear operator): it is by definition a nonzero polynomial in $X$ of minimal degree that vanishes when the matrix is substituted for $X$, and therefore generator of the ideal of all polynomials that vanish. But then saying that the characteristic polynomial $P_A$ vanishes under substitution of $A$ for$~X$ (which is what the Cayley-Hamilton theorem does) amounts precisely to saying that $P_A$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial, $f$ in the question.